# Looping through JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

using Chrome Developer Console, if I do this:

```
> target_url = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%201g5DrXcdotCiO_yffkdW0zhuJk0a1i80SPvERHI8"

> $.getJSON(target_url + '&jsonCallback=?', function(data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); });
```

this returns all the flight info from the Fusion Table, what is the correct way to extract the data and use it within the javascript, in particular i am interested in drawing/animating the flight path onto a raphael map?

thanks

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) :)

Comment: What does the data look like when you log it to the console?

Comment: we need to see what the ajax returns in order to offer any help.

Comment: you can try it on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out

```
$.getJSON(target_url + '&jsonCallback=?', function(data) { 
  console.log(data.table.cols);
  for(var i = 0; i < data.table.rows.length; i++) { 
    console.log(data.table.rows[i]);
  }
 });
```

thanks